# Kafka Streams - Global State Store restoration before stream threads starts processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have Global State Store attached my topology. Global state store in reading from compacted topic. This global state store stores 100,000 records and these records should be there in state store for correct processing of the topology.

Question:
Q. During application restart, kafka streams will start the global state store thread and make sure that the state is fully built before starting streams threads ?

I am trying to find some documentation related to this topic
Please point me to code or documentation also.

Comment: Yes, a global store is loaded completely before processing starts.

Comment: @SunilS Could you please share how you initialized a global state store with compacted Kafka topic?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if there is still any state remaining in the `state.dir` local filesystem for your `application.id`.

If there is, it'll start rebuilding data onto there. Otherwise, the beginning of the topic will have to be consumed to recreate that data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as I see in source code of KafkaStreams.start():

```
if (globalStreamThread != null) {
     globalStreamThread.start();
 }
```

GlobalStreamThread.start():

```
 @Override
    public synchronized void start() {
        super.start();
        while (stillInitializing()) {
            Utils.sleep(1);
            if (startupException != null) {
                throw startupException;
            }
        }
```

GlobalStreamThread.stillInitializing()

```
 public boolean stillInitializing() {
        synchronized (stateLock) {
            return state.equals(CREATED);
        }
    }
```

GlobalStreamThread.run():

```
@Override
public void run() {
    final StateConsumer stateConsumer = initialize();
    ...
    setState(RUNNING);
    ...
}
```

It seems that restoring of Global Stores happens before start of stream processing.
Also I tested that by putting millions data to topic for Global Store and the main logic didn't start while store wasn't restored completely.